# Workflow Pick activity not sending reply until Action complete

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow that contains a Pick activity. Each PickBranch is triggered by a WCF request. The triggered branch then sends a response to the request and performs an Action activity. But the behaviour I'm seeing indicates the response is not being sent until the Action activity is complete which is causing the original request to timeout, depending on how long the Action activity takes to complete.

[image]

In the PickBranch above, I'm adding work orders to a mobile database. Each work order takes up to 16 seconds to be added to the database. As the number of work orders increases, the greater the likelihood that the original request will timeout. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I have a resolution for this. As per [Maurice's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868111/132599), I added a Delay activity following the SendReplyToReceive and the workflow then started behaving as expected.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Even tough this was answered a few years ago, did you find any final solution to this? I have the same problem and the Delay helps fix it. I was just wondering if there's anything better instead of using a workaround?

Comment: Hi Ricardo - 5 years is a long time in IT terms. Unfortunately I don't have access to the source for that project any more so I can't say whether I found a better alternative, sorry.

Comment: No problem at all. Thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and it works fine. If I have a Pick with a send and receive inside a trigger and a delay inside the action, the reply is received immediately.

Are you sure the Request on your SendReply activity appears to be set correctly?

Patrick is still right, you should implement your database activity as an AsyncCodeActivity but this would not be the reason for your reply being delayed.

Comment: Thanks Peter. This particular workflow is only exercised infrequently and an AsyncCodeActivity doesn't make sense in the context of the application. And no it doesn't work fine.

Comment: It is precisely because of the single threaded nature of workflow that you want to do AsyncCodeActivity implementations. This will free up the scheduler thread to schedule any additional activities onto the queue. I have used the same send/receive activity, pick pattern in highly concurrent workflow applications for a while now and I haven't seen this behaviour. If a delay would solve your problem then I suspect that properly defining IO bound operations to be async code activities would have the same effect as the reason would likely be the blocking calls on the scheduler thread.

Answer (score 0):

I my experience checking **PersistBeforeSend** on **SendReplyToReceive** to True fixes this problem. Putting Persist block after SendReplyToReceive also helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is working as intended. If the operations take such a long time, would you be better served by calling them asynchronously? Check out AsyncCodeActivity here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.asynccodeactivity.aspx

Comment: Really? That seems contrary to the order the workflow is displayed, i.e. receive request, send response, and then process the action. If the client has received the response it should be able to continue without waiting for the full workflow to complete.

Comment: The messaging in WCF workflow is meant to be used asynchronously per the description on MSDN, and everywhere else.  The async code activity is meant to be used when you have something asynchronous in an otherwise synchronous workflow.